How to extract the signature value from a certificate in PHP
i have a certificate :
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEvzCCBGSgAwIBAgITeAAARlJXpwVPUYDkbAABAABGUjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBi
MRUwEwYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxEzARBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgNnb3YxFzAV
BgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgdleHRnYXp0MRswGQYDVQQDExJQRVpFSU5WT0lDRVNDQTQt
Q0EwHhcNMjQwNzAyMDMxMTE2WhcNMjYwNzAyMDMyMTE2WjBJMQswCQYDVQQGEwJT
QTESMBAGA1UEChMJZnJlZSB0ZXh0MRIwEAYDVQQLEwlmcmVlIHRleHQxEjAQBgNV
BAMTCWZyZWUgdGV4dDBWMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKA0IABP/Lh6KN1Y5Z6CzW
+3hLkwGLUyorKQoCCQZzrbtvHNLocvv7OFDUHZZiOnwzhavZLkOEPjH8ojIH1kb1
A4LsTEejggMTMIIDDzB+BgNVHREEdzB1pHMwcTEgMB4GA1UEBAwXMS1TaGFFa3wy
LVNoYUVrfDMtU2hhRWsxHzAdBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEBDA8zMTExOTAyOTM3MDAwMDMx
DTALBgNVBAwMBDExMDAxDjAMBgNVBBoMBWphemFuMQ0wCwYDVQQPDARUZWNoMB0G
A1UdDgQWBBQJ9H6ej6E1lbOuT+RG6WI9yHrdATAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTHwOa3qd0S
yk89bWiCliFF8wF1pDCB5QYDVR0fBIHdMIHaMIHXoIHUoIHRhoHObGRhcDovLy9D
Tj1QRVpFSU5WT0lDRVNDQTQtQ0EoMSksQ049UFJaRUlOVk9JQ0VQS0k0LENOPUNE
UCxDTj1QdWJsaWMlMjBLZXklMjBTZXJ2aWNlcyxDTj1TZXJ2aWNlcyxDTj1Db25m
aWd1cmF0aW9uLERDPWV4dHphdGNhLERDPWdvdixEQz1sb2NhbD9jZXJ0aWZpY2F0
ZVJldm9jYXRpb25MaXN0P2Jhc2U/b2JqZWN0Q2xhc3M9Y1JMRGlzdHJpYnV0aW9u
UG9pbnQwgc4GCCsGAQUFBwEBBIHBMIG+MIG7BggrBgEFBQcwAoaBrmxkYXA6Ly8v
Q049UEVaRUlOVk9JQ0VTQ0E0LUNBLENOPUFJQSxDTj1QdWJsaWMlMjBLZXklMjBT
ZXJ2aWNlcyxDTj1TZXJ2aWNlcyxDTj1Db25maWd1cmF0aW9uLERDPWV4dHphdGNh
LERDPWdvdixEQz1sb2NhbD9jQUNlcnRpZmljYXRlP2Jhc2U/b2JqZWN0Q2xhc3M9
Y2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbkF1dGhvcml0eTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwPAYJKwYBBAGC
NxUHBC8wLQYlKwYBBAGCNxUIgYaoHYTQ+xKG7Z0kh877GdPAVWaBnNgtg+XFXQIB
ZAIBEDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAgYIKwYBBQUHAwMwJwYJKwYBBAGCNxUK
BBowGDAKBggrBgEFBQcDAjAKBggrBgEFBQcDAzAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNJADBGAiEA
2sVgVJidhX8lnKshVB4JL7YBY+F1p48JI7NPpO4xJDQCIQCWf97LYNEK7358msfA
RK1iTp3om8fnJ33A59SurRjENA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

and i want to get the signature value that is in this certificate.
i tried many solutions and this the closest one to the needed result.

$cert = openssl_x509_read($certificate);

openssl_x509_export($cert, $out, FALSE);

echo $out;


this solution gives me the whole information about the certificate , also the signature with them , but as string :

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            78:00:00:46:52:57:a7:05:4f:51:80:e4:6c:00:01:00:00:46:52
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: DC=local, DC=gov, DC=extgazt, CN=PEZEINVOICESCA4-CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul  2 03:11:16 2024 GMT
            Not After : Jul  2 03:21:16 2026 GMT
        Subject: C=SA, O=free text, OU=free text, CN=free text
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:ff:cb:87:a2:8d:d5:8e:59:e8:2c:d6:fb:78:4b:
                    93:01:8b:53:2a:2b:29:0a:02:09:06:73:ad:bb:6f:
                    1c:d2:e8:72:fb:fb:38:50:d4:1d:96:62:3a:7c:33:
                    85:ab:d9:2e:43:84:3e:31:fc:a2:32:07:d6:46:f5:
                    03:82:ec:4c:47
                ASN1 OID: secp256k1
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DirName:/SN=1-ShaEk|2-ShaEk|3-ShaEk/UID=311190293700003/title=1100/registeredAddress=jazan/businessCategory=Tech
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                09:F4:7E:9E:8F:A1:35:95:B3:AE:4F:E4:46:E9:62:3D:C8:7A:DD:01
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:C7:C0:E6:B7:A9:DD:12:CA:4F:3D:6D:68:82:96:21:45:F3:01:75:A4

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:ldap:///CN=PEZEINVOICESCA4-CA(1),CN=PRZEINVOICEPKI4,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=extzatca,DC=gov,DC=local?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint

            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:ldap:///CN=PEZEINVOICESCA4-CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=extzatca,DC=gov,DC=local?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7: 
                0-.%+.....7.............$......Uf...-...]..d...
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, Code Signing
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10: 
                0.0
..+.......0
..+.......
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:46:02:21:00:da:c5:60:54:98:9d:85:7f:25:9c:ab:21:54:
         1e:09:2f:b6:01:63:e1:75:a7:8f:09:23:b3:4f:a4:ee:31:24:
         34:02:21:00:96:7f:de:cb:60:d1:0a:ef:7e:7c:9a:c7:c0:44:
         ad:62:4e:9d:e8:9b:c7:e7:27:7d:c0:e7:d4:ae:ad:18:c4:34


this is the signature value :

the problem now , that this is a string, is there a way easier than this , that gives me object or something like that ?
i have tried openssl_x509_parse also , but it does not give me the signature

@brombeer it is showing the whole information about the certificate not extracting "the signature value only".

If you can change the library: phpseclib allows direct determination of the certificate signature.

@Topaco can you give me an example of its documentation? please

@Topaco thank you so much man, you are the best, I used it, and it worked. if you want you can write it as an answer to accept it.

You're welcome. I have put my comment as an answer.

You're not doing certificate validation yourself, are you?  There's a lot more to it than just checking signatures. Basic path validation is covered in RFC 5280 section 6, but there's more to validation than just path validation. Asking questions about how to get the signature from an X509 certificate is a strong sign you're not familiar enough with X509-based PKI to be doing custom validation. It's great if you're trying to learn how to do it as it's very useful knowledge but your first try is not something you want to use for real

@AndrewHenle Thank you for your comment, the problem is that I have a project to deal with invoices and these invoices should be E-invoices, and they ask to include the signature of the certificate in a certain field in the invoice. this is everything.

@momo Checking that the signature of some X509 cert matches a set of bytes doesn't verify anything - X509 certs are public. You could get the signature bits off the X509 cert Google uses for their search engine and having those bits doesn't prove you're Google. What you need to do is have the creator of the invoice use their private key to sign some data in the invoice in a specified way.  That is how they prove who they are - they have the private key that had to be used to create that signature.

(cont) You then use the public key of the X509 certificate to verify the signature.  And if you verify the X509 against a trusted certificate chain, that establishes your trust in the X509.  If I give you the 30:64:02:30:13:19:f0:9f:88:d6:e9:e5:88:82:... signature bytes from the stackoverflow.com X509 in your E-invoice, that would prove nothing.

(cont) You can use echo | openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 -servername stackoverflow.com | openssl x509 -noout -text to see stackoverflow.com's X509 certificate information, including the signature.

@AndrewHenle Thank you Andrew, but the problem here is that I am creating a client service, and also who has created this specification is the government, and they just said just put the signature in the invoice then send it to us... to be honest, they have done crazy things, but we can not say anything.

phpseclib allows the direct determination of the certificate signature, s. Reading Certificates in the phpseclib documentation.
The certificate is loaded with X509#loadX509() which returns an array with the three certificate fields tbsCertificate, signatureAlgorithm and signature (s. RFC 5280). The latter contains the signature.
Sample code:
use phpseclib3\File\X509;

$certPem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

$x509 = new X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509($certPem);
$signature = $cert["signature"];
print(bin2hex($signature) . PHP_EOL); // 003046022100dac56054989d857f259cab21541e092fb60163e175a78f0923b34fa4ee312434022100967fdecb60d10aef7e7c9ac7c044ad624e9de89bc7e7277dc0e7d4aead18c434

$signature = substr($signature, 1);   // remove leading 0x00
print(bin2hex($signature) . PHP_EOL); // 3046022100dac56054989d857f259cab21541e092fb60163e175a78f0923b34fa4ee312434022100967fdecb60d10aef7e7c9ac7c044ad624e9de89bc7e7277dc0e7d4aead18c434

For the certificate posted, the signature is an ECDSA signature in ASN.1/DER format, which you can analyze in an ASN.1 parser, e.g. here.
Note that for some reason a leading 0x00 is prepended (maybe the last byte of the preceding BIT STRING encoding 0x034900, s. here), which should be removed for a valid ASN.1/DER signature format.

thank you, about the 0x00 that is in the first, I think it is a space, I got rid of it using trim like this:  bin2hex(trim($cert["signature"]))

@momo, don't do that. trim will remove legitimate bytes from some signatures, making them invalid. It appears to work because 0x00 is one the bytes that trim removes, but it removes both at the start and end and it doesn't stop after the first one.

@momo - ASN.1/DER encoded ECDSA signatures start with 0x30 (SEQUENCE), which is why ltrim() (but not trim(), s. Peter's comment) would be an option. However, other signatures (e.g. RSA) may well have leading 0x00 values that are part of the signature, so that even ltrim() could strip too much. It is therefore more robust to specifically remove the leading 0x00 byte.

@Topaco thanks , but how to solve it ?

@momo - Just use substr(..., 1) instead of trim()/ltrim().
